# VS Code Extension: TreeItem command property how to issue vscode.open

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to open a file when my treeView items are clicked (similar to how the default explorer opens a file). However, I'm stuck on implementing this feature. From my understanding, one way to implement this is to define the `command` property of the `TreeItem` type, as seen [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem). This link also says:

> Please use `vscode.open` or `vscode.diff` as command IDs when the tree item is opening something in the editor. Using these commands ensures that the resulting editor will appear consistent with how other built-in trees open editors.

As seen [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands), `vscode.open` takes in some arguments, in particular it needs a uri of a text document. I'm very confused at how to pass that argument to this command in this manner. I tried:

```ts
class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem {
    children: FunctionsTreeItem[]|undefined;

    constructor(label: string, filePath: string, children?: FunctionsTreeItem[]) {
        super(
            label,
            children === undefined ? TreeItemCollapsibleState.None :
                                    TreeItemCollapsibleState.Expanded);
        this.children = children;
        
        this.command = {
            title: "",
            command: "vscode.open",
            arguments: [{"uri": filePath}]
        }
```

or with the `arguments` line modified to just `[filePath]`. Neither works. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Maybe try `[{ fileUri: filePath }]` judging from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122071#issuecomment-826279707.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: make the URI a member of the TreeItem, you get the treeitem as argument in the command, or `arguments: filePath`, the first argument of `vscode.open` is the URI

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an example from one of their issues. The code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-references-view/blob/730800271aa5ef52b1c49608d68f14ee585f7821/src/calls/model.ts#L176-L186) gives a very good example.

So, the syntax is just this:

```
arguments: [Uri.file(filePath)]
```

Comment: Could you possibly post the full solution, showing how you have changed the TreeItem extender to accommodate the arguments array.? I'm facing the same issue and I don't understand the solution: how to apply the arguments array to the TreeItem. Would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is what I had at the end
`this.command = <Command>{title: "",command: "vscode.open",arguments: [Uri.file(filePath),(some other commands)]};`